# Como faco para selecionar algumas linhas de publicos diferentes?

Tags: sql

Preciso selecionar um publico dentro de algumas condicionantes.

- As 3 primeiras linhas do `GRUPO 1`
- A primeira linha do `GRUPO 3`

  **Caso não tenha primeira linha no `GRUPO 3`**:

  - A primeira linha do `GRUPO 4`
  - A primeira linha do `GRUPO 2`

    **Caso não tenha a primeira linha do `GRUPO 4`**
    Então em vez de selecionar só a primeira linha do `GRUPO 2`, deve selecionar 2 linhas.

Estou tentando rankear e pegar isso com `case when`, mas esta complicado. Algume me ajuda?

Obrigada.

Tenho uma tabela de publico no seguinte formato:

| CLIENTE | GRUPO | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 |
| 103 | 1 | 4 |
| 104 | 1 | 5 |
| 105 | 2 | 1 |
| 106 | 2 | 2 |
| 107 | 2 | 3 |
| 108 | 2 | 4 |
| 109 | 4 | 1 |
| 110 | 4 | 2 |

Tabela Final Pego os 3 primeiros do `GRUPO 1`, a primeira linha do `GRUPO 4` e a primeira do `GRUPO 2`

| CLIENTE | GRUPO | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 |
| 109 | 4 | 1 |
| 105 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: bem vinda Juliana. Leia sua pergunta e tente pensar nas pessoas que não conhecem as tabelas, os campos, nada, não tem como ajudar. Coloque na pergunta o modelo de dados e query que já tem, e um exemplo do resultado esperado

Comment: Será que fazer o UNION dos selects com as devidas condições não seria uma abordagem melhor do que com CASE/WHEN?

Comment: Qual seu `SGBD`? Consegue colocar na sua pergunta o `script` de criação de tabelas e inserção dos dados?

Answer (score 1):

Interpretando "caso não tenha primeira linha" como não existindo registros nesse grupo, tente:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 1 ORDER BY CLIENTE LIMIT 3) a
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 3 ORDER BY CLIENTE LIMIT 1) b
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 4 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 3) ORDER BY CLIENTE LIMIT 1) c
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 3)ORDER BY CLIENTE LIMIT 1) d
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE GRUPO = 4) ORDER BY CLIENTE LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) e
)
ORDER BY CLIENTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Juliana, segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando uma CTE para obter a quantidade de linhas dos grupos para depois utilizar essa quantidade na clausula Where:

```
with CTE_Count as
(
    select
        count(case when Grupo = 2 then 1 end) as QtdGrupo2,
        count(case when Grupo = 3 then 1 end) as QtdGrupo3,
        count(case when Grupo = 4 then 1 end) as QtdGrupo4
    from Tabela
)

select
    t.*
from Tabela as t
cross join CTE_Count as c
where
    (t.Grupo = 1 and t.Rank <= 3) or
    (t.Grupo = 3 and t.Rank = 1) or
    (t.Grupo = 4 and t.Rank = 1 and c.QtdGrupo3 = 0) or
    (t.Grupo = 2 and 
        (
            (t.Rank = 1 and c.QtdGrupo3 = 0) or
            (t.Rank = 2 and c.QtdGrupo3 = 0 and c.QtdGrupo4 = 0)
        ) 
    )
```

Espero que ajude